# Model methods are not working in sails js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js

I am using sails v0.12 ,  I have different models  in my MySql relational database but the area of concern lies in these 2 models which are 
1. User
2. Appointment

I want to add  apptCustomer and apptProvider data into appointment model 
but the value is NULL in the database

My User model is :

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
    },
    email: {
      type: "email",
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },
    contact_no:{
      type: "int",
      maxLength: 15,
      //required: true,
    },
    address: {
      type:"longtext",
     //required: true,
    },
    userId:{
      type: "string",
      primaryKey: true,
      unique:true
    },
    gtoken:{
      type: "string"
    },
    provider:{
     type:"string"
    },
    cancel:{
      type: "boolean",
   //   required: true
    },
    business_name:{
      type:"string",
      unique:true
    },
    business_category:{
      type:"string"
    },
    roles:{                                                 // Many to Many = User <-> User-role <-> Role 
      collection:'Role',
      through:'userrole',
    },
    services:{
      collection:'Service',
      through:'serviceprovider',                          // Many to Many = User (provider) <-> Service-provider <-> Service
    },
    schedules:{                                             // One to One = User (provider) - Schedule
      collection:'Schedule',
      via:'owner',
    },
    providerAppointments:{                                       // One to Many = User(customer) - multiple Appointments
      collection:'Appointment',
      via:'appProvider',
    },
    customerAppointments:{                                      
      collection:'Appointment',                                    // One to Many = User(provider) - multiple Appointments
      via:'appCustomer'
    }

  }

};
```

And my Appointment Model is

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    appointment_id:{
      type:'int',
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    appointmentDate: {
      type: 'datetime',
      required: true,
    },
    start_time: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
    end_time: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    status: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['booked', 'canceled']
    },
    appProvider: {
      model: 'user',
    },
    appCustomer:{
      model: 'user',
    },
    serviceAppointment: {
      model: 'service',
    }
  }
};
```

And my Model Methods are as follows

```
 Appointment.findOrCreate({appointmentDate:req.body.values.appointmentDate, start_time:req.body.values.start_time, end_time:req.body.end_time, status: status},{appointmentDate:req.body.values.appointmentDate, start_time:req.body.values.start_time, end_time:req.body.end_time, status: status})
                    .exec(function apptCreated(err,appt){
                        if(err) { sails.log('err',err)}

                        Service.findOne({ service_id : req.body.values.selected_service})
                                .exec(function(err,service){
                                    service.serviceAppointments.add(appt);
                                    service.save(function(err,result){
                                        if(err) { sails.log(err)}
                                    })
                                }), 
                        User.find({userId: req.body.businessId})  
                            .populate('roles')
                            .exec(function(err,provider){
                                _.map( provider.roles, role => { // Problem lies here .. this method is not working
                                  if(role.role_id==1){
                                    provider.providerAppointments.add(appt);
                                    provider.save(function(err, result){
                                        if(err) { sails.log(err)}
                                        sails.log('appointment added to provider')
                                    })
                                }  
                            })
                        }),                  
                        //Appointment adding to Customer
                        User.find({userId: req.body.customerId})  
                            .populate('roles')
                            .exec(function(err,customer){
                                _.map( customer.roles, role => { // Problem lies here... this method is not working
                                  if(role.role_id==2){
                                    customer.customerAppointments.add(appt)
                                    customer.save(function(err, result){
                                        if(err) { sails.log(err)}
                                        sails.log('appointment added to customer')
                                    })
                                }  
                            })
                        }),

                        // Adding contact to customer 

                        User.update({userId: req.body.customerId},{ contact_no: req.body.values.contact_no}) // this method works fine
                            .exec(function userUpdated(err, user){
                                if(err) { return sails.log(err)}
                                sails.log('contact number updated',user);
                        })

                })
```

Comment: I think you should use something link `async.each` or `async.eachSeries` since `.save` is a blocking call. You can find more about it here: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

Comment: @khushalbokadey I tried with async.each but it didnt have any effect , if you can be more specific about this solution then it would be great

Comment: Also, it should be `appt.id` in `.add()` method as mentioned in the docs here. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/populated-values/add

Comment: appt.id doesn't make any difference , also the .add(appt) in findOne method is working just fine the problem is when I map over provider/customer roles , it makes duplicate entries in the database with values of apptCustomer/apptProvider as NULL @khushalbokadey

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, at the moment that you call `provider.providerAppointments.add`, `provider.providerAppointments` is still just a regular property - possibly an array of ids.

I think you need to add `.populate('providerAppointments')` to your `User.find`... if you do that, then `provider.providerAppointments` should have a `.add` method that works the way you expect.

Of course, if this is the source of error, I would have expected a pretty clear error message, like `provider.providerAppointments.add is not a function` or some such. But try adding the populate, see if it fixes your problem.